# TypeScript: Arrow function parameter causes Property is missing in type '{}' but required in type error

Tags: typescript

According to [TypeScript's documentation on interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces),

> An *interface declaration* is another way to name an object type.

If that's the case, why do I get an error in the code below? I'm trying to "narrow" down the `object` type in the arrow function parameter with an interface.

([TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwCoHsDKwBOBLAdgcygF4oAKFRALigoQgGNgBKYgPigGcs98BuAKH55gETADMAhvWgAFURxS4oAb35QouCQFsI1LjgICAvoPqKuUSJgW5UGA-mrxk6bgWJla1OdcUsi7LQAdJo6AgD04VBIABbYHFD0EgCuHBAJwDHQopgomOoFhUWFAHpl5YL8kVAAEigA7hAAbqIANFAAkokSShIcHNj4vVAABj42IzSIDMBQwChQElBNEjgScAA20Chio7Qzk6CQUIC8G4DiO1D8W7NeU3SMAma4FlY23vKKHsoa2rpQAESoLT-KBGAS0DyvRS8IA))

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
}

type ObjToString = (obj: object) => string;

const personToString: ObjToString = (obj: Person) => obj.name;
// This causes the error                  ^^^^^^
```

Error message:

```
Type '(obj: Person) => string' is not assignable to type 'ObjToString'.
  Types of parameters 'obj' and 'obj' are incompatible.
    Property 'name' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Person'.
```

However, I can assign a variable of type `Person` to a variable of type `object`:

```
let obj: object;
const person: Person = { name: "Tom" };
obj = person;  // OK
```

Is there any reason why the error occurs at the arrow function parameter only? How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object` type itself does not have any properties. And that is the issue you are getting. `object` is a very restrictive type.

If you want to use any type of object, just use `any`.

```
type ObjToString = (obj: any) => string;

interface Person {
  name: string;
}

const personToString: ObjToString = (obj: Person) => obj.name;
```

[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwCoHsDKwBOBLAdgcygF4oAKFRALigENcQBKYgPigGcs98BuAKF7zAImAGY0AxtAAKwtilxQA3ryhRcNALYRqHHAT4BffuPkcokTHNyoMe-NXjJ0nAsTIUE1GZflMirDwA6dS0+AHowqCQAC2w2KHEaAFc2CHjgaOhhTBRMVXyCwoKAPVKy-l4IqAAJFAB3CAA3YQAaKABJBLpaNjZsfAUaKAADbythqA8IcWAoYBRaKEaaHBo4ABtoFBERqZmJ0EgoQF4NwHEdqF5N2Y9qPeA+E1wzCysvWXk3RTVNbSgAIlQGj+UAMfA8bhe8m4QA)

Also, Typescript's behaviour is such that does not complain when you pass extra properties to a type which was expecting lesser properties. But it would definitely complain is the minimum required properties are not present.

Look at this example :

```
interface Student {
  school : string;
  name : string;
}

interface Human {
name : string;
}

let x : Student = {
  name: 'Test',
  school: 'Test'
};

let y : Human = {
  name : 'test'
};

// x = y;
y = x;
```

The statement `x=y` will give an error but `y=x` will not do it. You can assign `Student` to `Human`, but not `Human` to `Student`.

[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgK4BMLmQbwChlkBnBACwHsqAbZALjLClAHMBuY5EOAWxRNSLdlwC+hQqEixEKABIY+cEAUK8BjZqxCdCEwrQhhkADy3psuEwF41JDRCYByACoRhzgDTdy1Oi7unvpchsbIAJ5aisqqdkQO-ILIzpDBYqEA9JlmyHYRXFF2phxAA)

That is what is happening in your code, TS is complaining because `Person` requires `name` and it is missing in `object` ({}). `object` requires nothing and `name` is just an extra property being passed to the variable `obj`.

[Related](https://lemoine-benoit.medium.com/why-does-typescript-sometimes-fails-to-type-check-extra-properties-fd230ebbc295)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign a function that requires a `Person` object to a function that is typed to accept **any** object. IOW, you could then call `personToString` as follows:

```
personToString({ whatever: "hello" });
```

Obviously this cannot work, which is why the compiler complains.

Answer (score 1):

The TypeScript `object` type represents all values that are not in primitive types.

The main issue here is trying to access a property called 'name' from an 'object' which is translated to {} and does not have 'name' property.

you could help Typescript understand what you are trying to do by using generics:

```
    interface Person {
      name: string;
    }
    type ObjToString<T> = (obj: T) => string;
    const personToString: ObjToString<Person> = (obj: Person) => obj.name;

    const aPerson: Person = {name: 'test_name'};
    const aPersonName = personToString(aPerson);
    console.log(aPersonName)
```